# GitLab's only:changes and the first commiit in a branch

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a multi-module build with one "leading" module and one additional one. I have set things up so that the additional module is only built when either it or the build files have changed:

```
build:sbt:module-main:
  extends: .build-sbt

build:sbt:module-a:
  extends: .build-sbt
  only:
    changes:
      - module-a/**/*
      - project/**/*
      - "*.yml"
      - "*.sbt
```

The behaviour I observe is that in a pipeline resulting from pushing a new branch, both modules are always built, regardless of the actual changes. Then when new commits are pushed to the branch, the pipelines triggered off of those will behave according to my rule, i.e. module-a will only be built when there was a change that affects it.

I would expect the same behaviour from the start.

I assume that "change" means "what git thinks has changed between this branch and the branch it was based off of". Is that not what change means in this context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While searching for another answer I discovered by accident that Gitlab [is working as designed](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/issues/19232) in this case.

Comment: as a side note, it's unfortunate that Tobias Baumann's proposal in the linked thread got brushed aside quickly. I'm not convinced by the reasoning given for discarding it :-/